# Removing inline CSS from HTML files using Perl

Tags: html, css, perl, cpan

We have about 100+ HTML files which were written years ago and all of those files contain inline CSS. Now we are trying to extract out the CSS from those files and create separate files for CSS (stylesheets). So in this process first we want to clean all our HTML files (removing CSS from them).

I want to know is there any perl module which can do this job? I searched on CPAN but didn't get any. Perhaps my search query was not matching with desired module. Let me know if there exists such module. If it doesn't then I'm gonna write a module for that.

Comment: Any reason why it has to be perl?

Comment: Because I code only in Perl, and since the job is related to manipulate text files I don't think any other language can do this job better than Perl.

Comment: By javascript you can do this easily.

Comment: If you share some code it will be better to sort out.

Comment: are you talking about style attributes within elements or style elements, or maybe both?

Comment: both, just want to keep tokens/tags, class, id, alt, href, target, title and the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is by using [HTML::Restrict](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aRestrict).  Just tell it which tags and attributes you want to keep and everything else will be removed.  From the docs:

```
use HTML::Restrict;

my $hr = HTML::Restrict->new();
$hr->set_rules({
    b   => [],
    img => [qw( src alt / )]
});

my $html = q[<body><b>hello</b> <img src="pic.jpg" alt="me" id="test" /></body>];
my $processed = $hr->process( $html );

# $processed now equals: <b>hello</b> <img src="pic.jpg" alt="me" />
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks for making this module oalders :)

Comment: Using HTML::Restrict I'm not able to save javascript functions like `onLoad`, `onMouseDown` from HTML tags like `<body onLoad=xyz()>` returns only `<body>`

Comment: @ChankeyPathak try adding onload to your body rules (lower case). Also, I saw your review about preserving comments. There's an undocumented allow_comments (you'll see it in the source code) which you can use to preserve comments.  I wasn't sure about the api, so it's hidden until I firm up the naming there.  If that doesn't work, feel free to post a new question with code and we can tackle it there.

Comment: Thanks oalders, it worked. Please add the allow_comments in documentation so that it may help others too.

Answer (score 5):

This should be pretty straightforward with any decent HTML parser (I'm a fan of [`HTML::TokeParser`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTokeParser), but there are others). You would iterate through all the tokens in an HTML document. When you find an HTML tag that has a `style` attribute (are there other attributes that define inline CSS? I'm not an expert here), you would remove that attribute before outputting the tag. You would output the other tokens without modification.